# splitting bash string by delimiter (last line with delimiter) into array

Tags: regex, bash

I'm having a hard time splitting a string like this:

```
444,555,text with, separator
```

into this:

```
444
555
text with, separator
```

i.e. into a 3-element array (last element may contain comma)

I tried sed but I end up having 4 elements due to the last comma.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

With bash and array:

```
s='444,555,text with, separator'
IFS=, read -r a b c <<< "$s"
array=("$a" "$b" "$c")
declare -p array
```

Output:

```
declare -a array='([0]="444" [1]="555" [2]="text with, separator")'
```

Comment: @cmks: I assume that  BestCoderEver knows how to output strings or arrays.

Comment: I did my comment before you applied many edits to your post. Furthermore as  BestCoderEver may not build a working sed script for this challenge I wouldn't assume that he can. And he taged this question with `regex` so I guessed he is interested in a solution with sed and regex.

Comment: @cmks: Yes, your comment was referring to [this version](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8ea6fb1d-0306-4649-b47d-4830fba790be/view-source) of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` editor allows replacing the ***number*** th match of the *regexp*(i.e. the ***k***-th occurence of the string within a line):

```
str="444,555,text with, separator"
sed 's/,/\n/1; s/,/\n/1' <<< $str
```

The output:

```
444
555
text with, separator
```

---

`s/,/\n/1` - `1` here is a *number* flag which points to the first occurrence of `,` to replace with `\n`

The following will give the same result(implying the first match on each substitution):

```
sed 's/,/\n/; s/,/\n/' <<< $str
```

Two consecutive substitutions will give 3 lines(chunks)

Comment: @jm666, agreed, just wanted to explain the matter of  **number**th match for the OP

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "444,555,text with, separator" | sed  "s/\([0-9]*\),\([0-9]*\),\(.*\)/\1\n\2\n\3/"
```

Output:

```
444
555
text with, separator
```